# How can I install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Tags: boot

I have a tablet PC running windows 8.1 but I want to install Ubuntu. It has UEFI.

How to do it?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

In the installation after you mame the partitions there will be a popup asking you if you want a UEFI installation. it will only show if Ubuntu detects that the tablet has UEFI.